# How to copy Netscape email

Tags: thunderbird, email-client, seamonkey

I think I have the Netscape mail-directory from old computer, how do I copy it to new computer?

(Netscape 7.1 Mail, Thunderbird or Seamonkey).

---

I think I have the files in 
Olduserbackup\xjuwtwtb.slt\Mail

I create a new mail account with server pop.superuser.com, and find a directory with that name in 
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Profiles\default\ou6umlif.slt\Mail

I replace the files with those from the backup, but Netscape still shows pop.superuser.com in its interface.

Is there some kind of registry setting somewhere I will have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest removing the entire `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Profiles\default\ou6umlif.slt` folder from the new machine, and replacing it with the `xjuwtwtb.slt` folder out of the backup.  That should transplant the entire profile from the old machine, rather than just copying the emails, which is probably the desired result in any case.

Comment: I think perhaps:

Comment: 1) You have to replace the content of the folder.

Comment: 2)  Set the Local folders settings (Through GUI)

Comment: I also want to mention this link:

Comment: http://sillydog.org/forum/sdt_6550.php